# Extended ascii in java files

Tags: java, android, character-encoding

When I try to save a .java file in eclipse with a character from extended ascii, for example █ it returns the following error

```
Save could not be completed. Try File >Save as if the problem persists
Reason:
Some characters cannot be mapped using "Cp1252" character encoding.
Either change the encoding or remove the characters which are not 
supported by the "Cp1252" character encoding.
```

And I have the option in the dialog for saving the file as UTF-8. If i do it, will eclipse continue compiling correctly? or is possible I'll introduce errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use unicode, not extended ascii.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Block_elements lists the ASCiiesque block characters.